# What would be the most time efficient way to find the subsequences of length LIS?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sequence, dynamic-programming

Given an array(vector) sequence.
I need a method or a fix possibly that will find all the increasing subsequences with the length of the longest increasing sequence.
So for example: **[1, 3, 2, 5, 2]**
should output:
**1 3 5 and
1 2 5**

1 3 5 is the first LIS length of 3.
Then the next one is 1 2 5.

I've already implemented something it works for smaller instances but as soon as I have a larger sequence array(size: 1000+) the program takes forever.

Here is my function for the length of LIS: it uses dynamic programing and works really fast

```
int findLISLength(const std::vector<int>& sequence, size_t n) {
    std::vector<int> lisEnd(n + 1, 0);
    std::vector<int> parent(n, 0);
    int length = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int low = 1;
        int high = length;
        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (sequence[lisEnd[mid]] < sequence[i])
                low = mid + 1;
            else
                high = mid - 1;
        }
        int pos = low;
        parent[i] = lisEnd[pos - 1];
        lisEnd[pos] = i;

        if (pos > length)
            length = pos;
    }

    return length;
}
```

Here is my function for finding all increasing subsequences with a given length.
This is where the time complexity is really high cause of the three for loops.
I tried recursion aswell and it takes just as much time.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> getAllIncreasingSubsequences(const std::vector<int>& sequence, size_t length) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> dp(sequence.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sequence.size(); ++i) {
        dp[i].push_back({ sequence[i] });
        for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            if (sequence[i] > sequence[j]) {
                for (const auto& subseq : dp[j]) {
                    if (subseq.size() + 1 <= length) {
                        auto newSeq = subseq;
                        newSeq.push_back(sequence[i]);
                        dp[i].push_back(newSeq);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (const auto& subseq : dp) {
        for (const auto& sub : subseq) {
            if (sub.size() == length) {
                result.push_back(sub);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I read the sequence numbers from a file then call the functions.
The sequence is:
[43629 88099 89706 22748 1174 68526 8869 61079 64279 2965 56809 3540 94669 72740 94999 18126 …]

```
int main(){
    size_t L = findLISLength(sequence, N);
    vector<vector<int>> 
        increasingSubsequences = getAllIncreasingSubsequences(sequence, L);
    //print subsequence
    cout << "L: " << L << endl;
    cout << "Increasing subsequences: " << endl;
    for (auto& subsequence : increasingSubsequences) {
        for (auto& element : subsequence) {
            cout << element << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: See also: [Finding All possible Longest Increasing Subsequences](/q/9554266).

Comment: I've already tried it but its also for 1000+ elements time consuming.

Comment: (Time for output not only depends on amount. One common advice for line output with C++ is to use `std::endl` when a "flush" is wanted, only. Especially in loops, use '\n' (it should be "translated" to "\r\n" where necessary).)

Comment: Is there a good reason you are constructing all subsequences in advance instead of generating them one by one? Also, calling a variable `dp` does not automatically make your program faster. You never _do_ anything with `dp` for subproblems. Did you notice that the linked answer refers to calculating the longest possible subsequenece for a given position?

Comment: @greybeard This is not the main point of the program, Im probably gonna output into a text file.

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate because it does appear to be asking the exact same thing as the linked question. If there is a reason why you think that your question is different, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how your code was trying to work, so I decided to rewrite in a way that is both clear to me, and is fairly efficient. If the answer is `m` increasing sequences of length `k` out of a list of length `n`, my algorithm will be `O(n^2 + m*k)`.

Note that `m` can grow exponentially with the size of the vector. The worst case is a vector with the  structure `[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, ..., n, n-1]` then there will be `2^(n/2)` maximal increasing sequences. The number of increasing sequences is almost certainly why your code was too slow. That's why I'm printing as I go. With the first 2 lines giving an idea how bad it will be.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Make it easy to print a vector.
template <typename S>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<S>& vector)
{
    // Printing all the elements
    // using <<
    for (auto element : vector) {
        os << element << " ";
    }
    return os;
}

void printAllIS(const std::vector<int>& seq) {
    size_t n = seq.size();
    int maxSize = 0;
    std::vector<int> listSize;
    std::vector<int> countLists;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> nextIndexes;

    // initialize empty data.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        listSize.push_back(0);
        countLists.push_back(0);
        std::vector<int> next;
        nextIndexes.push_back(next);
    }

    // Go from the end of the sequence backwards.
    for (int i = n-1; 0 <= i; i--) {
        int size = 1;
        int count = 1;
        std::vector<int> next;

        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (seq[i] < seq[j]) {
                if (size < listSize[j] + 1) {
                    // Reinitialize to only count lists of this size.
                    size = listSize[j] + 1;
                    count = 0;
                    next.clear();
                    if (maxSize < size) {
                        maxSize = size;
                    }
                }
                if (size == listSize[j] + 1) {
                    // This is a next index, record it.
                    count += countLists[j];
                    next.push_back(j);
                }
            }
        }
        // Now that we have the answer, save it.
        listSize[i] = size;
        countLists[i] = count;
        nextIndexes[i] = next;
    }

    int count = 0;
    vector<int> next;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (listSize[i] == maxSize) {
            count += countLists[i];
            next.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    // Indicate how big the answer will be.
    cout << "Size of sequences: " << maxSize << endl;
    cout << "Number of sequences: " << count << endl;

    // Indicate how big the answer will be.
    cout << "Size of sequences: " << maxSize << endl;
    cout << "Number of sequences: " << count << endl;

    /*
        The data structure for printing is 3 vectors of the same size.
        Think of it as a vector of frames with:

        - value = seq[i]
        - indexIter = iterator through nextIndexes[i]
        - indexIterEnd = nextIndexes[i].end()

        Each time we come back to a frame we discard the value. If
        iteration is done at this level, we throw away the rest of
        the frame. Otherwise we stack up frames until we are ready
        to print again.
    */
    vector<int> values;
    vector<vector<int>::iterator> indexIters;
    vector<vector<int>::iterator> indexIterEnds;

    // initialize. Note, we'll discard the value immediately.
    values.push_back(0);
    indexIters.push_back(next.begin());
    indexIterEnds.push_back(next.end());
    while (0 < indexIters.size()) {
        // Done with this value.
        values.pop_back();
        auto indexIter = indexIters.back();
        auto indexIterEnd = indexIterEnds.back();
        if (indexIter == indexIterEnd) {
            // Throw away the rest of the frame.
            indexIters.pop_back();
            indexIterEnds.pop_back();
        }
        else {
            while (true) {
                // Start stacking frames.
                int i = *indexIter;
                // Add a value - they are now equal.
                values.push_back(i);
                indexIters.back() = ++indexIter;
                indexIter = nextIndexes[i].begin();
                indexIterEnd = nextIndexes[i].end();
                if (indexIter == indexIterEnd) {
                    // Ready to print!
                    cout << values << endl;
                    // All done the printing loop.
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    // Add the rest of the next frame.
                    // The value will be added at
                    // the start of the next loop.
                    indexIters.push_back(indexIter);
                    indexIterEnds.push_back(indexIterEnd);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vect{2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9};
    printAllIS(vect);
}
```